# Need help installing Technic Pack when I have Sphax Texture pack on

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mcpatcher

I am following the instructions to the letter, but something goes awry somewhere.

On a clean MC install, I patch the game using MCPatcher, with all the options except Better Grass on. Then, I move the texture pack in the right folder (with the addons for EE, BC and IC2). After that, if I try to install the Technic Pack, it breaks the whole setup.

Any help?

Comment: Not all mods in the TP can work with this texture pack. I don't know, how a texture pack can affect that, but since the official page has "MODS supported" section - something isn't right (maybe every block has to have a 128x texture).

Comment: I thought EE, BC and IC2 were all the mods that needed textures, and they have them from the Sphex addons. Or are there others?

Comment: Well, there are much more mods in the TP, like Redpower, Railcraft, Forestry, Millenaire, Zeppelin, and lots of addons to them, which have their own items/blocks.

Comment: I didn't see any options for RedPower, Railcraft or Forestry when I  installed it, unless they are hidden and you can't choose to not install them, and I didn't install Millenaire, but I did install Zeppelin, which would make your comment spot on :P

Comment: I've never used the SSP version of TP, but I do have an SMP installed, and there were no extra options available to choose whether to include these mods or not, they are core elements of TP (excluding the Millenaire and Zeppelin, they are SP-only). You can check your `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods` folder to see, which mods do you actually have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Technic pack includes Optifine, which has support for HD Textures included. Try installing the technic pack first over a vanilla (un-modded, un-changed) version of minecraft. Then put the texture pack in `C:\Users\yourname\Appdata\Roaming\.minecraft\texturepacks` (on Windows), you can also type `%APPDATA%` in the address bar in windows explorer and navigate to `.minecraft\texturepacks`.

If this does not work try following the instructions in the "If you have previously used MCPatcher" section of [this Minecraft Forum post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/249637-100-optifine-hd-d2-fps-boost-hd-textures/).

Comment: I'll try that and report back.

Comment: Worked just fine.